# integrating Tomcat 7.x with Eclipse Juno

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I recently installed Tomcat 7.0.34 and Eclipse Juno IDE . I have configured everything correctly .

My port 80 was occupied by another server , so i changed it to 81 for Tomcat by double-clicking the server tab and changing the HTTP/1.1 to 81 .

My server started without problems but i am not able to view the Tomcat Homepage .

Searching , i tried to select "use tomcat installation" but it still does not work for me and gives "Page cannot be displayed" when i type

```
http://localhost:8081/
```

Help will be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I don't believe the embedded Tomcat server has a ROOT web application.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis : Strange , i resolved it myself by typing in

    http://locahost:81/ instead of http://localhost:8081

But i guess when i changed from 80 to 81 , by default it should prefix "80" in front.

Thanks for looking into it